# CDF of mixture of Normal standard and Poisson

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let Y be normal standard distribution and Z be Poisson distribution with i.e lambda = 1. Suppose a random variable such as X is defined as follows: (flip a coin)

X = Y (if Heads occurs)
X = Z (if Tails occurs)

I want to know the figure of the CDF of the X?!

I tried to achieve this which I do know whether it is true or not:

$F_X(t) = P(X \le t) = P(X \le t | heads)P(heads) + P(X \le t | tails)P(tails)=$

$=\frac{1}{2}P(Y \le t) + \frac{1}{2} P(Z \le t) = \frac{1}{2}[F_Y(t) + F_Z(t)]$

so, how can I plot the figure of the CDF of X?

Comment: Your procedure is correct. You have a linear combination of the c.d.f. and also of the p.d.f.

Comment: You can plot the sum of the c.d.f. for example using Python or any software with some support for statistics.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I also plotted Empirical CDF of this random variable with Matlab, as the Matlab shows, it is a continues form with shape like _/ (a horizontal line starts from 0 to near 0.25 with CDF value equal to 0.5, and from near 0.25 to almost 0.35 it looks like a line with positive slope). I can not imagine why the CDF of the X looks like: _/, and I want to understand it mathematically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plot made in *Mathematica*.  The blue curve is the standard normal CDF, the orange piecewise function is the Poisson CDF, and the green is the desired mixture.  Due to the discrete nature of the Poisson distribution, its CDF has jump discontinuities at each nonnegative integer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the empirical CDF plotted by the Matlab, makes me confused! Thanks a lot